# Validation error of an RDF Document with Oxygen

Tags: xml, rdf

I have a little problem with understanding the RDF Framework, especially when I am trying to validate the following document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:dc11="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:ns0="http://example.org/stuff/1.0/">
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-syntax-grammar">
        <dc11:title>RDF/XML Syntax Specification (Revised)</dc11:title>
        <ns0:editor>
            <rdf:Description>
                <ns0:fullname>Dave Beckett</ns0:fullname>
                <ns0:homePage rdf:resource="http://purl.org/net/dajobe/"/>
            </rdf:Description>
        </ns0:editor>
    </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

As you can see the document is well-formed, but when I am trying to validate the document I get an valiadation error in Oxygen which means that there is no schema or dtd assigned. Is there a way to do that? The example is from the W3C page, Point 2.3 Example 4 https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-rdf-syntax/ .

The simple question is:
What should I change, that the validation of the document in Oxygen is successfully? Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing. There is no normative DTD or XML Schema published for RDF/XML, so there's nothing you can do to make Oxygen validate this (unless you're prepared to write a DTD or XML Schema yourself).

Using XML validation on RDF/XML is not very useful anyway: even if it's valid with respect to some XML Schema, that doesn't tell you anything about whether or not it's actually a valid RDF model.

If you want to check whether your RDF is valid, you should use an RDF Validator instead. There's several tools that can do this for you, including an [online service by the W3C](https://www.w3.org/RDF/Validator/).

Comment: ok, thank you that means, check the document for Well-Formedness or use the toools. Anyway thank you for answering :-)